# Why doesn't my submit button work?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

The form is available when the user clicks a modal. When I click the submit button in the modal, it button does not work.

```php
foreach ($posts as $post) { echo '
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#$id_user">Validasi</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
';
}
```

Here is the modal:

```php
echo '
<div id="$id_user" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content" id="registerContent">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <div class="modal-text-header text-center">Validasi</div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="container-fluid">'; echo '
          <form class="form col-md-12 center-block" action="http://localhost/MMM/admin/validasi/'.$id_user.'" method="POST" enctype=\ "multipart/form-data\">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-control input" placeholder="Dana awal (RP.1.000.000,-)" type="text" name="dana">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn btn-block" name="submit" value="Submit">
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>' ;
```

Comment: At least one error that I see - `$userid` in the first snippet is in single quotes, and won't be interpolated. Aside from that - please do not use Stack Overflow web snippets except for executable HTML/CSS/JS code. We cannot run your PHP code inline, so the extra capabilities of the web snippets are just noise; please format as the normal code block, with simple 4-space indent.

Comment: It looks like your for loop isn't generating valid markup... E.g. There are no opening TRs

Comment: thanks before, the problem is when click the submit button, is not work. The modal is work correctly
There is the picture 
https://scontent-sin1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xta1/v/t1.0-9/11800237_1136792013004889_1926958099226822865_n.jpg?oh=39ef98e1c1a472719b02d4b18fc4abe6&oe=563FED41

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the submit button has been passed then run the code. This will ensure that you won't get an undefined index error.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 // Your code here.
}
```

Also use form (`<form></form>`) tags to specify POST request in `method="post"`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use echo with single quote: that's what's making your headache. Create code like this:

```php
<div id="<?php echo $id_user ?>" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content" id="registerContent">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
        <div class="modal-text-header text-center">Validasi</div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <form class="form col-md-12 center-block" action="http://localhost/MMM/admin/validasi/<?php echo $id_user ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-control input" placeholder="Dana awal (RP.1.000.000,-)" type="text" name="dana">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn btn-block" name="submit" value="Submit">
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this other code:

```php
<?php 
foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
<td>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#$id_user">Validasi</button>
</td>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Also read [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

### Errors

1. Wrong placement of `<form>` open and close
2. Miss-Match Character in `enctype=\ "multipart/form-data\"`, (`\`).

So **Final Well-Form Code** is

```
<div id="$id_user" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content" id="registerContent">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <div class="modal-text-header text-center">Validasi</div>
            </div>
            <form class="form col-md-12 center-block" action="http://localhost/MMM/admin/validasi/'.$id_user.'" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control input" placeholder="Dana awal (RP.1.000.000,-)" type="text" name="dana">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            **
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn btn-block" name="submit" value="Submit">**
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** You are not uploading any `Files` in your form. So No use of  `enctype`